# Disable click anywhere except one cell (in the selected row) when a cell enters the edit mode

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

How do I disable `click` on all grid cells except one cell in a row? I am trying to disable clicks on any cell in the grid, when a cell enters the edit mode. So I tried:

```
$('#QCStatus tr td').bind('click',function() {
        return false;
});

//QCStatus is the id of the grid
```

To enable click on a cell, in the same row that is being edited, I tried:

```
$('#QCStatus tr.selected-row td[aria-describedby="QCStatus_ActionIcons"]').bind('click',function() {
        return true;
});
```

But this doesn't have any effect as click is disabled by the first snippet. What is the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Try `event.stoppropagation()`

Comment: Can you do this?  '$('#QCStatus).bind('click',function() {
        //identify your cell and do something   //else, return false
});'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can exclude the selected row it with `:not()` here:

```js
$('#QCStatus tr:not(.selected) td').on('click', function(e) {
  $('pre').prepend('event :::: '+e.type+'\n');
  return false;
});
```

```css
.selected{background:yellow;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id='QCStatus'>
  <tr><td>click</td></tr>
  <tr class='selected'><td>click</td></tr>
  <tr><td>click</td></tr>
  <tr><td>click</td></tr>
</table>

<pre></pre>
```

This will bind the click on all the `td`s which are not the children of `tr.selected`.

---

As per your comment you can add more:

*How could I just exclude the td in the selected row `td[aria-describedby="QCStatus_ActionIcons"]`?*

```
$('#QCStatus tr:not(.selected) td:not([aria-describedby="QCStatus_ActionIcons"])').on('click', function(e) {
  $('pre').prepend('event :::: '+e.type+'\n');
  return false;
});
```

Comment: How could I just exclude the `td` in the selected row `td[aria-describedby="QCStatus_ActionIcons"]`?

Comment: Same way you can add this: `$('#QCStatus tr:not(.selected) td:not([aria-describedby="QCStatus_ActionIcons"])')`

Comment: What will be the best way to remove the `click` handler just added? `(or to revert to the default state i.e make everything clickable)`

Comment: I guess you need to use `.off()` and `.on()` to bind/unbind the events.

Comment: It could unbind all the click events associated with it? I just need to unbind the current event attached.

Comment: Actually this is quite complicated better to post a new question.

Answer (score 1):

> Use [`event.stoppropagation()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) for element to be eliminated for `click` event. It prevents further propagation of the current event.

```js
$('tr').on('click', function() {
  console.log('clicked!');
});
$('.disabled').on('click', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td class="disabled">Disabled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td class="disabled">Disabled</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Hello</td>
    <td class="disabled">Disabled</td>
  </tr>

</table>
```

[**Fiddle here**](https://jsfiddle.net/y8f16o6L/)

Answer (score 0):

add a "disabled" attribute to those buttons where you want to disable the click.

for a div disabled attribute doesn't work.

in those cases use "pointer-events:none;" in your css of that particular divs.